# Haskell let expression converges while similar expression using fix does not

Tags: haskell, mutual-recursion

I have been having difficulty understanding why the haskell expression `let (x,y) = (y,1) in (x,y)` converges to `(1,1)` as expected but `fix (\(x,y)-> (y,1))` results in `<<loop>>` being thrown.  Can anyone explain this?

Comment: the fix expression is equivalent to `let g (x,y) = (y,1) ; r = g r in r`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default, the outermost patterns used in `let` bindings are lazy. However, patterns used in lambda bindings are strict, so the pattern match against the tuple forces too much too early. You can explicitly write a lazy pattern match by prefixing it with `~`, making the lambda pattern equivalent to the `let` pattern:

```
ghci> fix (\(~(x, y)) -> (y, 1))
(1,1)
```

This defers the actual evaluation of the pattern match until one of bound variables is forced, instead of when the function is called, avoiding the loop.

For more information, see the [Haskell wiki article on lazy patterns](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lazy_pattern_match).